# How do I append a column from a numpy array to a pd dataframe?

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a numpy array of 100 predicted values called first_100. If I convert these to a dataframe they are indexed as 0,1,2 etc. However, the predictions are for values that are in random indexed order, 66,201,32 etc. I want to be able to put the actual values and the predictions in the same dataframe, but I'm really struggling.

The real values are in a dataframe called first_100_train. 
I've tried the following:

```
pd.concat([first_100, first_100_train], axis=1)
```

This doesn't work and for some reason returns the entire dataframe and indexed from 0 so there are lots of NaNs...

```
first_100_train['Prediction'] = first_100[0]
```

This is almost what I want, but again because the indexes are different the data doesn't match up. I'd really appreciate any suggestions.

EDIT: After managing to join the dataframes I now have this:

[image]

I'd like to be able to drop the final column...

Here is first_100.head()

[image]

and first_100_train.head()

[image]

The problem is that index 2 from first_100 actually corresponds to index 480 of first_100_train

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set default index values by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `drop=True` for correct alignment:

```
pd.concat([first_100.reset_index(drop=True), 
           first_100_train.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Or if first `DataFrame` have default `RangeIndex` solution is simplify:

```
pd.concat([first_100, 
           first_100_train.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very close to it - now I have an issue where the last column still shows all the NaNs - I've tried dropping it by index, do you know any other way I could drop it? Thanks for your help

Comment: @Raph117 - For me it is not easy test, because no data. Is possible add some sample data, e.g. for 10 rows and test for `first_10` ?

Comment: Hi jezrael, I just added some more details in the question, and you can see the dataframe

Comment: @Raph117 - Is possible add to question `print (first_100.head(10)` and `print (first_100_train.head(10)` ?

Comment: @Raph117 - It should working, modify second solution.